# "No transaction is in progress" error while following Grails Spring Security Core tutorial

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security

I'm following the Grails Spring Security Core tutorial [in their documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/4.0.x/index.html#tutorials). When I reach 24.1.5.5, the problems start. I'm instructed to modify Bootstrap.groovy to the following, then run the app:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp

class BootStrap {

   def init = {

         def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()

         def testUser = new User(username: 'me', password: 'password').save()

         UserRole.create testUser, adminRole

         UserRole.withSession {
            it.flush()
            it.clear()
         }

         assert User.count() == 1
         assert Role.count() == 1
         assert UserRole.count() == 1

   }
}
```

Running the app gives me this error:

> 2020-03-31 15:46:19.294 ERROR --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>                : Application run failed
>
> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in
>   progress
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl
>   .java:3586)

I've attempted to use @Transactional to solve this, but it had no impact on the error. Reverting Bootstrap.groovy to its default allows the application to run normally. What is missing (or incorrect) from this tutorial that is causing it to fail?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation is out of date. Hibernate 5.2+ requires transactions for write operations now. Adding the @Transactional did not work because `init` is a closure and the annotation applies to methods or classes.

Create a new method in bootstrap and add transactional to it. then call it from your init closure. For example.

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = {
        addTestUsers()
    }

    @Transactional
    void addTestUsers() {
        def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()

        def testUser = new User(username: 'me', password: 'password').save()

        UserRole.create testUser, adminRole

        UserRole.withSession {
           it.flush()
           it.clear()
        }

        assert User.count() == 1
        assert Role.count() == 1
        assert UserRole.count() == 1
    } 
}
```

Comment: I've created a PR to update the docs https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/pull/613

Comment: I'm afraid this results in the same error for me. Is there additional configuration that needs to be done before this point?

Comment: What database are you using/configured? I assumed you were using a hibernate datasource.

Comment: I'm using a mysql database, with the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver driver and org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect dialect.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I can't reproduce - if you upload a project to github or something it may help identify the issue.

Comment: Here's a blank project other than the tutorial's instructions, the database info, and your suggested modification: https://github.com/dylan-goss/securitytest

Comment: https://github.com/dylan-goss/securitytest/blob/master/grails-app/init/securitytest/BootStrap.groovy#L3 - you are using spring's transactional - please use GORM's and all should work :)

Comment: That did it! 16 years of PHP is catching up with me.

Comment: I found the same problem in an abstract DataService, to override the save method. Why? I dunno.

Comment: also the default generator seems to use import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional . I changed to import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional and it worked

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the solution in https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11376, where say that you can add to application.yml the config

```
hibernate:
    allow_update_outside_transaction: true
```

Comment: It's not the best solution, but it works